# Set LinearLayout abode fragment and TableLayout below fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I think the solution is really easy but I cannot figure it out.
The page is basicly devided into 3 pieces. Top is a linearlayout that can be as high as the content inside. On the bottom an table layout the can be as high as the content as well and between the fragment. I cannot figure out how to give the fragment the control to take the rest of the space left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Status:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Switch" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Use Linearlayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```